# Why Intel x86 Atom System Image (API 15) is missing in AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator

I run android tool and downloaded Android 4.0.3 SDK and 2.3.3 SDK, including Intel Atom x86 System Image.

I launched AVD Manager and tried to create an emulator. I can see Intel Atom images for 2.3.3, but not for 4.0.3.

I tried to reinstall it, but still don't see it in AVD.

Has anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: In Android SDK Manager does "Intel x86 Atom System Image" show up under "Android 4.0.3 (API 15)"?

Comment: Oh... Thank you. I didn't notice that. For API 10, it's standalone item and I anticipated that this one would be standalone item too.

Comment: Ok, I'll write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Android SDK Manager`, `Intel x86 Atom System Image` should show up under `Android 4.0.3 (API 15)`.